# CSS code fails to make changes to HTML code

Tags: html, css

I have HTML code that is not linking with the CSS file.

I have posted the code below.

When ever I try to make changes to the CSS file and save, nothing happens to the browser preview.

I used CSS code that I have used before, and know it is correct.

But that CSS file doesn't show up on the browser preview.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Moses Saygbe LAb 3 </title><!--Title of page-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="tex/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<main>
<form id="apptf" class="header">
  <h2>Family Medicine Practice</h2>
  <header class="header">
    Patient Information
  </header>
  <fieldset class="header">
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
  <div>
    <label for="first">First Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="header">
  </div>  
  <div>
    <label for="last">Last Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="last" id="last" class="header">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="dphone">Daytime Phone</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="dphone" id="dphone" class="header">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="ephone">Evening Phone</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="ephone" id="ephone" class="header">
  </div>
  <div id="visit-first">
    <label for="visit">Is this your first time visiting our office?</label><br>
    <input name="visit" type="radio" id="visit" value="Yes"> Yes
    <input name="visit" type="radio" id="novist" value="No"> No
  </div>
  </fieldset>
  <header class="header">
    Appointment Information
  </header>
  <fieldset class="header">
    <legend>Appointment Time</legend>
    <div>
      <label for="appointment">Date</label>
      <input type="date" name="appointment" id="appointment" class="header">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="time">Time</label>
      <select name="time" id="time" class="header">
        <option value="8am">8AM</option>
        <option value="10am">10AM</option>
        <option value="12pm">12PM</option>
        <option value="4pm">4PM</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="moreinfo">
      <label for="moreinfo">Please describe the reason for the visit</label><br>
      <textarea class="moreinfoh" name="moreinfo" id="moreinfo" cols="10" rows="10">. 
      </textarea>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
   <button type="submit" value="submit" class="header">Submit</button>
   </form>
   <footer>
    Moses Saygbe 2020
   </footer>
   <script>
  window.onload=function(){ //diable right click
      document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  },false);}            
   </script>
</main>
```

And here is the CSS code. I tried relinking it, opening in a new browser. Still nothing fixes it.

```
@charset "utf-8";
html, body{ 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(7, 7, 7);
    background: url(../Week3lab/graphic/aldebaran-s-zzi-6FCQtF8-unsplash.jpg) no-repeat 
center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: What is it that you want to change specifically? can you give an example?

Comment: I'm trying to add a background to the page and nothing is displaying. Its just white. The link to the image is this.  https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588894167282-408680bb62f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=756&q=80

Comment: I posted an answer, please look.

Comment: @BHD721 is it possible that your browser is caching the CSS code? or that you are using a service like Cloudflare that could be caching your CSS file. can you try and put the CSS in the head of the html using style tags and see if that helps? here's a link if you dont know what i mean https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_style.asp

Comment: It worked, Would clearing my cache and cookies help clear that so i can put it in a seperate doc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does making your CSS this work?

```
  @charset "utf-8";
html, body{ 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588894167282-408680bb62f4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=756&q=80");
    z-index: -1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how i would be able to clear the old cache data. I need to have the code in a seperate css file